# Problem in working out an exercise of topology.

Tags: general-topology

**The question is** :

Let $X$ be any non empty set and $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ where $\mathcal P(X)$ denotes the power set of $X$.Consider the set

$\Sigma_{\delta} = \{A \subseteq X : A\ is\ the\ intersection\ of\ finitely\ many\ sets\ in\ \Sigma \}$.Then show that

(1) $\Sigma \subseteq \Sigma_{\delta}$.

(2) $X \in \Sigma_{\delta}$.

(3) $\Sigma_{\delta}$ is closed under finite intersections.

I have easily shown (1) and (3).But I don't find any way to prove (2).If $X \notin \Sigma$ then how can I show that $X \in \Sigma_{\delta}$?Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of the empty family of subsets? It is a finite family, since it has 0 elements. Its intersection is X.

Comment: Yes, only under this interpretation one can state (3).

Comment: @VictorZurkowski please be more explicit.I dont understand properly what you have said.I also saw this interpretation as a hint in M.G.Murdeshwar's General topology though I have failed to undestand it properly.Please help me in overcoming such confusion.

Comment: According to my view if I take two subsets $S$ and $T$ of $\mathcal P(X)$ such that $S \subseteq T$ then the intersection of all the sets belonging to $T$ is a subset of the intersection of all the sets belonging to $S$.Now empty family of subsets of $X$ is the smallest possible finite subset of $X$.So the intersection of the empty family of subsets of $X$ gives rise to the largest subset of $X$ which is $X$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

More formally we could write:

$$\Sigma_\delta = \{\bigcap \mathscr{F}: \mathscr{F} \subset \Sigma \text{ finite }\}$$

where $\bigcap \mathscr{F} = \{ x \in X: \forall F \in \mathcal{F}: x \in F\}$

So if we take $\mathscr{F}  = \emptyset$, which is certainly finite, then

$\bigcap \emptyset = \{x \in X: \forall F \in \emptyset: x \in F\}$

which equals $X$ (as a statement of the form $\forall y \in \emptyset :\phi(y)$ is a tautology (you cannot refute it, as there are no elements to refute it with, a so-called voidly true statement.)

So $X$ is in $\Sigma_\delta$ as the empty intersection.